# Error Web Service Stunnel

Tags: stunnel

In Stunnel,I have this configuration:

```
[ws]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:80
connect = webservice.it:443
```

I make a http request to 127.0.0.1:80 and I want that stunnel redirect to webservice.it:443.

But it doesn't work.

In the log I have this error:

```
LOG6[]: Peer certificate not required
LOG7[]: TLS state (connect): before SSL initialization
LOG7[]: TLS state (connect): SSLv3/TLS write client hello
LOG3[]: SSL_connect: Peer suddenly disconnected
LOG5[]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
LOG7[]: Deallocating application specific data for session connect address
```

How can I do? Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that you can add `debug=debug` to your configuration raising log levels. Though it sounds like a protocol error. Can you tell us which version of stunnel and openssl are installed on both client and server?

Comment: For the server I don't know nothing unfortunally. For the client, I use stunnel 5.55 and openSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019